# Render an image in html template using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to render an image in my page. I stored the image's local url in my database so that I can get that url in my html file hence, display the image. But what happen is that the image is not displayed.

I opened the html file alone and the image was rendered successfully but when doing it in the python code and run the server, the image is problematic.

> This is a one item example of database declaration (python code)

```
cable1 = SectionItem(
name='Remax',
price='$3.99',
description='AUX Metal Cable - 3.5mm - 100Cm Male To Male',
image_url='img/cables/cable1.jpg',
category=cables
)
```

This works fine.

> This is the SQLAlechemy for rendering the image

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for,
flash
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database import Base
from database import Accessory, AccessorySection, SectionItem

app = Flask(__name__)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mobilystore.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/mobily')
def mobilystore():
    all_cables = session.query(SectionItem).filter(
        SectionItem.store_id == 1).all()
    return render_template(
        'mainpage.html', all_cables=all_cables)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Server also runs in terminal without problem.

> This is the html document in my templates folder

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Mobily Store</h1>
    </br>  
        {% for i in all_cables %}
        <div>
            <img src="{{i.image_url}}" alt="cable img">
            <p> {{i.description}} </p>
            <p> {{i.price}} </p>
    </br>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}

    </body>
</html>
```

the price and description is displayed but the image is not.

**Note that I put the images in img folder inside templates folder (the same folder contains my html file).**

this is the [my-project](https://github.com/omarelewa21/ItemCatalogProject) on github to give you a full insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move your `templates/img` folder to `static/img` and in your template print the image path with the `url_for` function:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=i.image_url) }}" alt="cable img">
```